# how to make a loop for every 20 seconds in timestamp column

Tags: python, machine-learning, timestamp

I have a dataset that is collected at around 500hz. for each second there are approximately 500 data points. but the frequency is not consistent all time. some times there are only 490 data points each second and sometimes there are 505 data points for each second. Is there a way I can write a loop using the DateTime object that extracts data for that particular period irrespective of change in frequency using python ?

I tried indexing for every 500 rows but this doesnt work.

my timestamp example :[image]

Comment: hi i want to use implement that in python

Comment: Could you post a small example of tour dataframe as text please?